# redux-form pass value to fieldarray fields

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using `redux-form` with an `FieldArray` and I'm trying to create different renderings depending on which button is clicked on.

assuming I have the following function (which is in the `component` attribut of a FieldArray in a form):

```
const renderCatalogCategories = (props) => {

const { fields } = props;

return (
<div>
    {fields.map((data, idx) =>
       <Panel key={idx} header={`${data}.type`} data={data} />
    )}


    <DropdownButton>
       <MenuItem onClick={() => fields.push({type: 'a'})}>a</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem onClick={() => fields.push({type: 'b'})}>b</MenuItem>
    </DropdownButton>
</div>) 
};
```

It is not possible to get the value of `type` which I pass in the `fields.push` on the MenuItems. You have an idea how I can get this value?

The value of `data` I get is just a string, e.g. `categories[9]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well posed question.

What you are looking for is [`fields.get(idx)`](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/FieldArray.md/#-fields-get-index-function-).

However, you will need the field name (what you have called `data`) to give to any `<Field>` component to edit your values inside the array.

Comment: `fields.getAll()` did the job too. Thanks!